# Centering text on specific point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a block of text, it could be just a few words or it could be multiple paragraphs. Within that block of text is an `<a>` that I want to always be displayed. However, I'm just line clamping to only view 2 lines of the text.

I've tried splitting the text in two and trying to manipulate each section to show what I want but this `<a>` could be the first or last thing in the text and all of the styling that I do with splitting it into two sections seems to break the flow of the text, especially in the edge cases

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So you’re wanting to show not the first two lines of your text block, but whichever two lines happen to contain your `<a>`nchor? Line clamping is so new that it’s not in any official specs yet, and it doesn’t provide this capability. You’ll need to change your design.